# Decoupling App and API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3

I am building an app in laravel which has 2 parts, the APP and API. So the major part is kind of API to the developers which am expecting a heavy traffic. The app is a simple interface for API key generation and reports.

As of now, the API and App are in the same project. However, am thinking of decoupling the app and API to separate projects. So here am confused since laravel now provide web and api routes in the same project. So which is the ideal way to do it, as a single project or separate projects?

Note: I will be having both projects on the same server (if decoupling is the option), so what will be the server impact of running two projects on the same server, assuming a RAM of 2GB.

Comment: @Kyslik yeah its running n Nginx + php-fpm

Comment: Look, if the app is going to attract many users you will most likely pour in more money so RAM 2GB or 6GM does not matter if you can not configure it properly. How does PHP app work: client hits nginx which if not cached sends request to php-fpm, application is loaded to RAM 32MB or maybe 64MB is used; code is executed and response is sent back to nginx (and to client). So RAM usage depends on how many users you have therefore 2GB or 512MB of RAM is irrelevant you can always buy more. Do cache everything if you can not pour more money to product.

Comment: In your case, it's have many solutions improved your server with traffic. If your server using SSD, you can use disk cache, create swap. You should use memcache, install varnish cache, index database,...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting it in one project. Use forge for server handling. Use digital ocean as your server. Add more digital ocean droplets as users increase. Usually people overestimate traffic to there sites.